# Rolling Sum Over Date index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code

```
data = {'date': ['2014-05-05', '2014-05-01', '2014-05-02',
                 '2014-05-02', '2014-05-02', '2014-05-02',
                 '2014-05-03', '2014-05-03', '2014-05-04',
                 '2014-05-04'],
        'battle_deaths': [34, 25, 26, 15, 15, 14, 26, 25, 62, 41],
        'group': [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'battle_deaths', 'group' ''])

df = df.set_index('date')
df.groupby('group').rolling(2).sum()
```

Which outputs

```
                 battle_deaths  group
group date                            
1     2014-05-05            NaN    NaN
      2014-05-03           59.0    2.0
      2014-05-04           66.0    2.0
2     2014-05-01            NaN    NaN
      2014-05-02           40.0    4.0
      2014-05-02           30.0    4.0
      2014-05-03           41.0    4.0
3     2014-05-02            NaN    NaN
      2014-05-02           40.0    6.0
      2014-05-04           76.0    6.0
```

But since the index is the date, I would expect for the first group that the `battle_deaths` column should have `NaN` value for date `2014-05-03`. In other words I would like to do the rolling sum within each group sorted by the `date`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That dataframe needs to be sorted, here is how i would do it.

```
df.sort_index().groupby('group').rolling(2).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think need convert dates to datetimes and sorting by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values('date').set_index('date')
df = df.groupby('group').rolling(2).sum()

                  battle_deaths  group
group date                            
1     2014-05-03            NaN    NaN
      2014-05-04           66.0    2.0
      2014-05-05           75.0    2.0
2     2014-05-01            NaN    NaN
      2014-05-02           40.0    4.0
      2014-05-02           30.0    4.0
      2014-05-03           41.0    4.0
3     2014-05-02            NaN    NaN
      2014-05-02           40.0    6.0
      2014-05-04           76.0    6.0
```